# can’t set ACLs on FreeBSD UFS

Tags: freebsd, acl

`$ sysctl -a | grep acl
kern.features.ufs_acl: 1
vfs.acl_nfs4_old_semantics: 0
$ mount
/dev/ada0p2 on / (ufs, local, journaled soft-updates)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, multilabel)
devfs on /var/named/dev (devfs, local, multilabel)
$ setfacl -m u:spamd:rwX ham
setfacl: ham: acl_get_file() failed: Operation not supported
$ getfacl ham
 # file: ham
 # owner: spamd
 # group: spamd
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x`

Any attempts to set acls with setfacl gives the same error, even commands copied directly from the man page.

Comment: Don't you have to enable acl's as one of the mount options?

Comment: Aha! Yes you do. Doh.

Answer (score 7):

The mount option `acls` must be specified to use ACLs, like such:

`mount -o acls /dev/ada0p2 /`

Or in fstab, like so:

`/dev/ada0p2     /                ufs     rw,acls         1 1`

This should make ACLs usable.

---

PS. Yes, I know this was answered in the comments just wanted to post this for completeness and so the question can be marked answered. Also, please specify the version of FreeBSD you are using when posting questions.

Comment: This is also documented on https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/fs-acl.html